# How to change identity provider callback URL in Keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, google-oauth, keycloak

I have a Keycloak server hosted in Kubernetes. When I request to external identity provider (like Google/Facebook), the hostname was used in the redirect url automatically. How can I change the redirect URL for my identity provider?

The auto generated redirect_url from Keycloak:
`http://keyclaok:8080/auth/realms/{MY_REALM}/borker/google/endpoint`

What I'm expected: 
`http://www.example.com/my-custom-callback/endpoint`, this url will redirect to the original keyclaok endpoint.

[My identity provider settings in Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvA9j.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto_generated redirect_url (shown in the UI) should not be relevant for you.

Afaik keycloak just build up the url with the current hostname you are accessing keycloak.
So when you access your admin console via

```
http://keyclaok:8080/
```

Redirect URL for a google Identity Provider is shown as

```
http://keyclaok:8080/auth/realms/{MY_REALM}/broker/google/endpoint
```

If you access keycloak over your domain

```
http://www.example.com/auth
```

and try to authenticate over google, the valid redirect URL will be

```
http://www.example.com/auth/realms/{MY_REALM}/broker/google/endpoint
```

In my opinion you can't decide how the redirect url will look like (especially not the suffix `realms/{MY_REALM}/broker/google/endpoint`), because it's relative to the keycloak base URL and keycloak needs it internally to map a answer to the correct realm and IDP
But I think you shouldn't have a problem with such a url, as long as keycloak is accessible over your domain

Comment: Thank you, It work for me! I added the endpoint to my API gateway so that the public (Google/Facebook) can only respond to the callback URL but not the admin console.

Comment: @KelvinLee Could you tell us if you used your custom URL via the API gateway and how you implemented it?